# Правомерно ли сравнение

Tags: лексика, сравнительный-оборот

> В 12:00 закроется большинство церквей, некоторые из которых богаче,
>   чем собрания большинства наших музеев.

Про "некоторые из которых" я уже спросила, а допустимо ли:

*церковь богаче, чем собрание?*

Как тут быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недопустимо, конечно. "Быть" можно напр. так: *из которых иные по своим собраниям икон богаче многих наших музеев*.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу какого-то грамматического или смыслового запрета. Но согласен, во избежание недопонимания стоит выразиться яснее, убрав заодно и нежелательный рефрен.

Как-то так:

***В 12:00 закроется большинство церквей, которые иногда богаче убранством, чем собрания многих наших музеев.***

Слово "собрание" по отношению к церковному имуществу не совсем точно, но, если совсем честно, то и идеальной замены я не вижу, менять надо по контексту.

Answer (score 1):

В 12:00 закроется большинство церквей, убранство которых способно затмить собрания некоторых наших музеев.